# Error with credentials_key instal sdk bing maps

Tags: android, sdk, bing-maps, credentials

Using Bing maps SDK, followed the install as per
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/sdk-native/getting-started-android/
This take from start of project in Android Studio to having map in application.

I followed the instructions and using this

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.{your_layout_file});
  mMapView = new MapView(this, MapRenderMode.VECTOR);  // or use MapRenderMode.RASTER for 2D map
  mMapView.setCredentialsKey(BuildConfig.CREDENTIALS_KEY);
  ((FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.map_view)).addView(mMapView);
  mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Error I am getting is CREDENTIALS_KEYS is red and and message = Cannot resolve symbol 'CREDENTIALS_KEY'

Comment: This is just placeholder code - You need to get your own key from the bing maps portal and supply it in your configuration. See the documentation under the getting started section for how to get your key.

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for the reply. I have got the key and followed the instructions. I added the secrets.gradle file containing the key. Made changes to the gradle app file etc.  For some reason no mater what I do always the same error, no errors in gradle files being reported.

Comment: Make sure you're following all the steps in the getting started documentation. It sounds like you might still be missing including the secrets file in your build. If you need another reference on how to set up your gradle files, you can reference the sample project here: https://github.com/microsoft/MapsSDK-Native/tree/master/Android/samples/sdksample

Comment: Without the contents of your build.gradle is going to be hard to provide more precise help.  Make sure you include an `apply from: 'secrets.gradle'` and to add the build config field later on for the corresponding build configuration (or for all of them). 

You could also try to enable more verbose logging in gradle to try to get more details and understand why that is not working.

Comment: I have the 'secrets.gradle' file as required with the key.

Comment: Hi Duncan, Thanks for the link, I have already been through the samples there. What I have done coincides with what they have.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly rebuild and import the app level BuildConfig